# Is this a good way to generate a chain of promises for an array?

Tags: javascript, promise

I have an array of items that I want to insert into an SQL server. I am using promises for this and in order to execute each insert sequentially I wrote the following method:

```
var ForeachPromise = function (array, func) {
  var promise = func(array[0]);

  for (var i=1; i < array.length; i++) {
    promise = promise.then(function() { return func(array[i]) });
  }

  return promise;
}
```

The idea is that when func is call it will return a promise, which will then be chained to the previous promise.

```
...
return ForeachPromise(type.subprocessen, function(subproces) {
    return newSubproces(subproces, typeId, dienstId, createData, s + 1);
});
```

I haven't actually tested it yet, but I assume that something like this will work. My question however is am I using promises correctly? Promises are great but easily misunderstood and I just want to be sure that I'm not making any fundamental mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that approach is fine, and works well with promises. Two minor quibbles:

- you should take care for the case of an empty array. Start your chain with `Promise.resolve()` (a promise fulfilled with `undefined`), and begin your loop at index 0.
- As the `then` callback is asynchronous, your `i` variable has the wrong value - the classical [closure in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/1048572) fallacy.

Using the [`.reduce` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) does help with both problems:

```
function foreachPromise(array, func) {
  return array.reduce(function(promise, elem, i) {
    return promise.then(function() { return func(elem) });
  }, Promise.resolve());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the great reply! I should have known about the closure in loop issue, as I have encountered it before. In any case I am glad that the approach I took was fine :)